# javascript textarea clear value on enter key

Tags: javascript, textarea, keycode

So, I was trying to make a textarea which when I press enter, it should submit the value then clear it.

The submit part was fine, however, instead of going back to the beginning of the textbox, it has a second line.

```
document.getElementById("content").blur();
document.getElementById("content").value = "";
document.getElementById("content").value.replace(/[\n]/i, '');
document.getElementById("content").focus();
```

I tried that to clear my textarea with the id = content, it still does not work....

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you don't want to keep saying `document.getElementById("content")` over and over. Instead say `var el = document.getElementById("content"); el.value = ""; el.focus();` and so forth. (Though if you're doing this in an event handler for that element the event object should already be giving you a reference to the element without needing to use `document.getElementById()` at all.)

Comment: yea, I didn't expect to use so many lines and still not working so I just copied them to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return false on the keydown event if the actual press was enter. That way the original event (new line to the textbox) won't be fired.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to ignore the enter key is to prevent the default behavior, which is inserting a `\n` character into the field.

In your event callback, simply call the event object's preventDefault method, like so `e.preventDefault()`. Also, be sure to wrap it in a conditional that prevents the default behavior for the enter key only (which is keyCode 13) if that's what you intend to do.

Comment: While preventDefault could achieve it, IE8 doesn't support preventDefault.